# I am trying to add data to a table in MysqlDB using python tkinter Module. I have created a UI where i am entering data. But it is not showing in DB

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am creating a Pharmacy Management System with the help of tkinter and Mysql Database.
I have created a front end for this project.
[FRONT END USING TKINTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjvot.png)

Now, For the Medicine add department Dataframe(The one on the right) I am trying to enter a value for Ref Number and Medicine Name which will be displayed on the table in Mysql Database. I have already created the table and DB in Mysql Workbench.
Below is the code which i am using to add Data into the Table.

```
def AddMed(self):
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password@123',
                        host='localhost', database='mydata',
                        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    my_cursor=conn.cursor()
    s="insert into pharma(Ref,MedRef) values (%s,%s)"
    b1=(self.addmed_var.get(),self.refmed_var.get())
    my_cursor.execute(s,b1)
                                                                        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Success","Medicine Added")
```

Also, Below is the code for Data Frame on the right:

```
# ===================DataFrameRight================
    
    lblrefno=Label(DataFrameRight,font=("arial",12,"bold"),text="Ref. Number",padx=2,pady=6)
    lblrefno.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)
    txtrefno=Entry(DataFrameRight,textvariable=self.refmed_var,bd=2,relief=RIDGE,width=29,font=("arial",13,"bold"),bg="white")
    txtrefno.grid(row=0,column=3)
    
    lblmedName=Label(DataFrameRight,font=("arial",12,"bold"),text="Medicine Name",padx=2,pady=6)
    lblmedName.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
    txtmedName=Entry(DataFrameRight,textvariable=self.addmed_var,bd=2,relief=RIDGE,width=29,font=("arial",13,"bold"),bg="white")
    txtmedName.grid(row=1,column=3)
```

I have also created two StringVar() variable for self.addmed and self.refmed.

But when i click on the ADD Button on my GUI, It is Not adding the data on the table. It seems like Nothing is happening at all.

Below is the code for the ADD Button which i am clicking to enter the data into the table(I have created a different frame for Button Section named down_frame):

```
btnAddmed=Button(down_frame,text="ADD",bg="lime",font=("arial",12,"bold"),fg="white",pady=4,width=8)
btnAddmed.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Why is this not adding data into the Database? How to resolve this?

Comment: Because you did not mention ```command=```. Right now , the command is ```None```. The button is not performing any function

Comment: `Button(..., command=self.AddMed)`

Comment: if you would add some `print()` in `AddMed()` then you would see that this function is never executed.

Comment: @furas i even tried changing command=self.AddMed but the data is still not showing up in DB.

Comment: did you add some `print()` to check if function is executed? Maybe you assigned to wrong button. OR maybe you write in different file. We can't see full code, we can't run it so it can't check if you have correct code.

Comment: @furas https://codeshare.io/wn9d3K I have shared the code. Try Running it. I am having issues in Addmed and Updatemed function. Refer to line 213 for the buttons. The other next two functions are working quite well. Please look into it. Thanks

Comment: @furas The function is even getting called properly. Refer to the UpdateMed function. The If statement there is executing properly when we try to Update a null value.

Comment: I can't run code from `codeshare` because I don't have database - and there is no code to create empty database.